# Either is or are

Tags: verbs

Is the following sentence incorrect?

> What India needs are honest leaders.

I think it is correct

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. See:
[American Heritage Dictionary "what" pronoun](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=what)

Here is the beginning of the usage note at the bottom of the page:

"When **what** is the subject of a clause, it takes a singular verb if the word or phrase that completes the sentence (the complement) is singular, as in **I see what seems to be a dead tree.** It is plural if a plural noun or noun phrase completes the sentence, as in **He sometimes makes what seem to be gestures of reconciliation.**"

Since the complement in your sentence is plural ("leaders"), "are" is correct after "what".